# Help in designing mysql table for large project

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am planning to create a website which allows **different Companies to register** in it. It will have **Employees module**. Each company will have a **CompanyId**. How do I maintain the Employees table, since in near future data sets may go extremely large. Kindly suggest which is appropriate. I am listing my intended designs, kindly suggest a better one .

**Note : The Employees of one company has no relation with employees of other companies.**

```
    Companies Table

    CompanyId CompanyName
    1       A
    2       B
    3       C
```

## Employees Table

## DESIGN 1:

```
DB : Companymanagement
Table Name : Employee
```

> Here the employees for a company are identified from the companyId

```
    EmployeeId      CompanyId   EmployeeName
    1       1(from companies table) Employee-A
    2       2(from companies table) Employee-B
    3       2(from companies table) Employee-C
```

## DESIGN 2:

```
DB : Companymanagement
Table Name : Employee_1
```

```
    EmployeeId      EmployeeName
    1               Employee-A
    2               Employee-B
    3               Employee-C

    Table Name : Employee_2
    EmployeeId      EmployeeName
    1       Employee-A
    2       Employee-B
    3       Employee-C
```

> Here the employees for a company are stored in individual tables with
>   companyid in table name ex Employee_1

## DESIGN 3:

```
DB : Companymanagement_1
Table Name : Employee
```

```
    EmployeeId      EmployeeName
    1       Employee-A
    2       Employee-B
    3       Employee-C
```

```
DB : Companymanagement_2
Table Name : Employee
```

```
    EmployeeId      EmployeeName
        1           Employee-A
        2           Employee-B
        3           Employee-C
```

> Here, the employees for a company are stored in individual databases
>   with companyid in database name ex Companymanagement_1

Kindly suggest me the right direction to manage datas. Sorry if I am vague.

Comment: There's good arguments for your first solution (called a "multi-tenant" database) and your third solution. It's hard to know exactly what is better withouth knowing your requirements better.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner My Idea is to develop a SAAS model, so each company and employee table are standalone , i.e they have no relation with other companies or employees, so the product will be hosted in a domain and each company will get access like a.companyxxx.com, b.companyxxx.com, c.companyxxx.com where a,b,c are different registered companies. Each logged in company administrators will access only the employees to their company alone, so above said was the idea behind my designs and struggling to get an appropriate design

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility of an employee to work in many companies such as Advisor or Instructor, the above designs will fail. 
There are possibilitites where one employee can work in more than one company.

So the perfect design would be the below

`Company_Id   Company_Name
   1          Aaaa
   2          Bbbb 
   3          cccc`

`Employee_Id   Employee_Name
   11          A
   22          B 
   33          c`

`Company_Id   Employee_Id
   1          11
   2          22
   3          33
   3          22`

This works in both the ways. One employee can work in many companies and many companies can have same employee. Many to Many relationship .